# Removing regedit key via powershell

Tags: powershell, command-line, regedit

I have been removing powershell and/or command line like below. My question is : Is there any equivalent inside powershell for /reg:64 parameter ?

CMD version:

```
reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TEST /v PropertyToRemove /f /reg:64
```

powershell version:

```
Remove-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SMS\Mobile Client" -Name "PropertyToRemove"
```

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's not implemented.

Reading this question: [Querying via powershell both 32bit and 64bit registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60553821/querying-via-powershell-both-32bit-and-64bit-registry)

it seems you should just be checking whether the os is x32 or x64 first
or run a check if the 64bit registry keys exists

Different topic, same question.. here's stated it's not implemented:
[How to access the 64-bit registry from a 32-bit Powershell instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630382/how-to-access-the-64-bit-registry-from-a-32-bit-powershell-instanceDiff)
look at whenrybruce's reply on the marked answer